# Capybara RSpec empty html - Nokogiri::CSS::SyntaxError: unexpected '$' after ''

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara, nokogiri

I have a simple web test scenario with Capybara running webrick and poltergeist, but it is driving me mad:

```rb
  let(:person) { create(:person) }
  scenario 'works with their password', js: true do
    # Login with password
    visit '/login'
    fill I18n.t('labels.email_address'), with: person.email
    fill I18n.t('labels.password'), with: person.password
    click_button(I18n.t('actions.login'))

    page.status_code.should == 200
    # Verify we are logged in
    within('header') do
      expect(page).to have_link "#{person.first_name} #{person.last_name}"
    end
  end
```

The response seems just fine, except that if I enter pry-rescue, the `page` is empty, leading to it obviously not finding the link in the header:

```
[9] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::UserLogin>)> page.all
Nokogiri::CSS::SyntaxError: unexpected '$' after ''
from /usr/local/lib/app-bundle/gems/nokogiri-1.12.5-x86_64-linux/lib/nokogiri/css/parser_extras.rb:90 `on_error'
[10] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::UserLogin>)> page.first
Nokogiri::CSS::SyntaxError: unexpected '$' after ''
from /usr/local/lib/app-bundle/gems/nokogiri-1.12.5-x86_64-linux/lib/nokogiri/css/parser_extras.rb:90 `on_error'
[17] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::UserLogin>)> page.html
=> ""
```

I have no idea what Nokogiri is even doing in here, looking like it is trying to parse jquery or something?

Comment: It's better to add your below answer to a question post above. else you might get downvotes on your answer @xeruf

Comment: include capybara tag

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is totally unrelated to the code:
The functions `first` and `all` require a parameter, and the error message is rather unclear that this is the issue.

Why `page.html` is empty remains a mystery to me.